# Как в Linq2Db вытянуть целиком дерево объектов?

Tags: c#, orm, .net-core, linq2sql, .netcore2.0

У меня есть древовидная структура типа

```
[Table(Name = "Category")]
public class Category
{
  [PrimaryKey, Identity]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Column(Name = "Name"), NotNull]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Column(Name = "Title"), NotNull]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  [Column(Name = "ParentId")]
  public int ParentId { get; set; }

  public int Parent { get; set; }

  public IList<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Как мне получить сразу всё дерево используя `Linq2Db`?

То есть надо что бы были заполнены `Parent` и `Children`.